# Как работает запись if($var){ ... } или if(!$var){ ... }?

Tags: php

Друзья всем привет!!! помогите разобраться раз и навсегда с этой записью, до сих пор сильно путаюсь, благодарю вас заранее.

Что означает запись `if($var) { echo "Hello"; }`

Или запись `if(!empty($var)) { echo "Hello"; }`

Я понимаю например запись

```
if(!empty($var) == TRUE) {
    echo "Hello";
} else {
    echo "Bye bye";
}
```

объясните разницу и как это работает? И где в короткой записи `else` использовать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию в подобного рода условиях проверяется истина. Т.е. запись `if(!empty($var))` идентична `if(!empty($var) == TRUE)` по смыслу. Т.е. `if(!empty($var))` читается как "Если в переменной не пусто, то".

Answer (score 2):

Выражение вида `$var == true`, вы воспринимаете его как обязательную часть `if()`. *Но это не так.* Поймите следующее: `==` это такое-же действие, как сложение или умножение:

```
$var = 5 + 3; //var = 8
$var = 5 * 3; //var = 15
$var = 5 == 3; //var = FALSE
$var = 5 > 3; //var = TRUE
$var = TRUE or FALSE; //var = TRUE
```

По сути PHP просто выполняет ваше выражение, не заботясь о том, какие там операторы, сложение, умножение или сравнение.

После того как все логические и арифметические действия выполнены, в `if()` уходит результат этих вычислений, `TRUE` или `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
if($var) { echo "Hello"; }
```

означает, что если значение **$var** можно привести к **TRUE**, то будет выполнена команда **echo "Hello"**. Смотрите последний столбце таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.

```
if(!empty($var)) { echo "Hello"; }
```

означент, что при не [пустом значении](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) переменной **$var**, будет выполнена команда **echo "Hello"**.

Больше информации в [таблице сравнения типов в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php) Обратите внимание на гибкое сравнение и жесткое сравнение.

3.

> И где в короткой записи else использовать?

```
if($var) { echo "Hello"; } else { echo "Bye-Bye!"; }
```

хотя лучше так ([тернарный оператор](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)):

```
echo ($var ? "Hello" : "Bye-Bye!");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Запись**

```
if($var) { echo "Hello"; }
```

аналогична

```
  if($var == true) { echo "Hello"; }
```

**Запись**

```
if(!empty($var)) { echo "Hello"; }
```

аналогична

```
if(!empty($var)==true) { echo "Hello"; }
```

или

```
if(empty($var)==false) { echo "Hello"; }
```

В "короткой" записи `else` ставите так же, как в "длинной":

```
if(!empty($var)){
  echo "Hello";
} else{
  echo "Bye bye";
}
```

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо !!! Я полностью разобрался, я правда год с этим путался, и наконец-то распутался)))